# Set-cookie from server to client not working in node angular 8

Tags: node.js, angular, api, cookies, cookie-httponly

Have to send cookie in header from node to angular client. Default it has set the cookie in API domain. If i set domain in cookies it's not working.

Please clarify which one is correct way to set-cookie?

```
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', ['token=' + token + ';httpOnly;Domain=abc.com;Path=/;secure:true;']);
res.cookie('token', token, { maxAge: 60*60*12, httpOnly: true,Domain=abc.com});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your API and angular app on different domains? If so, you will have to pass `withCredentials` option with the http call from angular. `withCredentials` is a boolean flag that indicates whether or not cross-site Access-Control requests should be made using credentials such as cookies, authorization headers or TLS client certificates. In addition, this flag is also used to indicate when cookies are to be ignored in the response. The default is false. XMLHttpRequest from a different domain cannot set cookie values for their own domain unless withCredentials is set to true before making the request. More details at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials)

Modify your angular HTTP call with `withCredentials` flag.
For GET

```
this.httpClient.get(url, { withCredentials: true})
```

For POST

```
this.httpClient.post(url, body, { withCredentials: true})
```

Comment: yes its in different domain,
and Sorry I forgot to mention, i already added  withCredentials: true in request